# Deducing the convergence of a sequence in the product space $\Pi_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ from the convergence of its components

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in the product space $X = \Pi_{i=1}^\infty X_i$, equipped with the product/box topology.

I would like to know conditions such that this statement is true: $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ converges to $x \in \Pi_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ $\iff$ $\pi_k(x_i)$ converges to $\pi_k(x)$ (where $\pi_k$ denote the projection to the $k$-th component).

For the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction: no conditions are necessary.

> Assume that $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ converges to $x \in \Pi_{i=1}^\infty X_i$. Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$. We would like to show that $\pi_k(x_i)$ converges to $\pi_k(x)$. Take any open set $U_k \subseteq X_k$ containing $\pi_k(x)$. Consider the open set $V = U_k \times \Pi_{i \neq k} X_i \subseteq X$. Since $x \in V$, we use convergence of $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ to obtain an $N > 0$ such that for all $i > N$, $x_i \in V$, which follows that $\pi_k(x_i) \in U_k$ as needed.

For the ($\Leftarrow$) direction:

> - If we equip $X$ with the product topology, then: For any open set $U \subseteq X$ containing $x$, $x \in \Pi_{k \in \lambda} V_k \times \Pi_{k \notin \lambda} X_k\subseteq U$ (where $\lambda \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite, and each $V_k \subseteq X_k$ is open). For each $k \in \lambda$, choose $N_k > 0$ such that for all $i > N_k$, $\pi_k(x_i) \in V_k$. Take $N = \max_{k \in \lambda} N_k$. Then, for all $i > N$, $x_i \in \Pi_{k \in \lambda} V_k \times \Pi_{k \notin \lambda} X_k\subseteq U$. So, $x_i \rightarrow x$.
> - If we equip $X$ with the box topology, then I am stuck since the maximum over the $N_k$'s may not exist. Am I missing any conditions for this statement to be true?

Comment: How can you prove the direct part without specifying any topology on $X$? Convergence is not even defined on $X$.

Comment: This question is very strange, if you do not consider the product topology (or any finer topology) on the product. And, in fact, then also "$\Rightarrow$" might be false: consider the indiscrete topology on the product.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have updated the description to specify that $X$ is equipped with the product or box topology.

Comment: You shouldn't call $X$ "product *space*", since usually this means $X$ equipped with the product topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is false in the box topology.  Take $2=\{0,1\}$.  Let $X=2^\Bbb{N}$ with the box topology.  This is the discrete topology on $X$, so a sequence converges iff it's eventually constant.  Now take the sequence
$$
\begin{split}
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1\ldots)\\
(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots)\\
(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,\ldots)\\
(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,\ldots)\\
(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,\ldots)\\
\ldots
\end{split}
$$
It converges pointwise to $(0,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$, but it's not eventually constant.